# there are stopped jobs, cannot logout

Tags: command-line, apt, ssh, openssh, logout

Im on a remote PC, where "there are stopped jobs, cannot logout".
But im leaving, and my connection will break. I tried killing the job, but it still says this.

```
$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
```

In the future, how can I safely log out, when this happens?

Comment: What is the output of `jobs`?  How did you try to kill the job? Which job?

Comment: can you put the job to the foreground with `fg`? can you get a job-ID and `kill ${ID}` it manually? Does the job need to run after you logout (so maybe `nohup job &` it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the Ctrl-Z shortcut, jobs can be pushed to the background.  Users of the screen command or the like often accidentally background jobs by forgetting they're not in a screen anymore.

using

```
fg
```

will bring a job to the foreground.

You can also check what processes are running under your user with:

```
ps aux | grep USERNAME
```

This will hopefully give you an indication of what was running, along with the process ID for that job.

You can then use:

```
kill PROCESSIDNUMBER
```

to stop that job.

I hope this helps!

Kind Regards